# What is actually Move To SD Card?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, app2sd

I recently moved  Dead Trigger 2 to my SD storage, but when I open my file explorer it still shows that Dead Trigger 2 is in my internal storage. When I checked my storage details it is showing only a 10MB difference, so I'm totally confused about the 'Move To SD storage' concept. I thought moving a 486MB game to SD storage is actually moving a 486MB game to SD storage, but my recent experience proves that I'm wrong. What is really meant by "Move To SD"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to App2SD, which are briefly explained in our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info). The App2SD built-in to Android only moves parts of the app to SDCard, while other parts (e.g. the app's data and its [dalvik](/questions/tagged/dalvik) cache) remain on internal storage. How much (or what percentage) gets moved varies from app to app – which is what you experience in the described case. Moreover, an app needs to explicitly support this mechanism.

There are different other approaches pre-installed with some custom ROMs (such as App2SD+), or separately installable on rooted devices (such as [link2sd](/questions/tagged/link2sd) or Data2SD) trying to fill this gap; to completely move an app out of internal storage, one often has to use combinations of at least two of those tools.

Please see the linked tag-wiki for closer details.